# How to make all Android library compatible with all Android versions?

Tags: android

My Android application is not working on Android versions like Kitkat and below versions. Please any one can help me for a solution. App gets unfortunately stopped on Kitkat.

Answer (score 0):

check your app level build to gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.app.ids"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),  'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE-FIREBASE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
}
}
```

change minsdk version according to your requirement

Comment: Actually i am using this library :-

Comment: compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1'

Comment: @dipali what is your minsdkversion in defaultConfig??

Comment: @dipali then some of libary not supported below kitkat version.

Comment: i am using this library  " compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.3.2' "

Comment: mehara  how can i make this library compatible with kitkat and below versions?

Comment: @dipali it is supported i am also using this library and it is supported in below 19 api